Keyboard shortcuts with three or more keys don't work on Manjaro with KDE
I installed Manjaro with KDE on my new laptop (MSI Titan GT77 HX 13V) few weeks ago.
From the first day none of three-or-more-key shortcuts is not working. Ctrl+Shift+Arrow for word level selection in any text editor (KWrite, VS Code, PyCharm), Ctrl+Shift+Tab in browser to return to the previous tab, Ctrl+Shift+F in PyCharm to Find in Files... or Ctrl+Shift+R to Replace in Files....
Shortcuts don't work on external and on built-in keyboards.
I've already tried to find any solution in the Web without any success.
PS: Speaking of the first shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Arrow. It looks like OS "sees" only Ctrl+Arrow (cursor jumps around a word without selection). I've tried to press Ctrl+Shift simultaneously and hold Ctrl than press Shift and than press Arrow. In both cases I'm getting the same (incorrect) behavior.
